# Are one of these directions true $ \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0 $ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L $ (L is finite)

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Is the following true? ( I can't find counter example for it )

$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0 $ $\Longrightarrow$ $ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L $ (L is finite)

if so, how do I prove it?

How about the other way around:
$ \lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=L $ (L is finite)  $\Longrightarrow$  $ \lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=0 $

Comment: $f(x) = \ln x$.

Comment: Or $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: What is true, is if $ f(x) \rightarrow L $ and $f'$ converges then the limit is zero

Answer (score 5):

No. Try for example $f(x) = \log x$.

EDIT: The converse is also false, although counterexamples are less trivial. Try
$$f(x) = \frac{\sin(x^2)}{x}.$$

EDIT 2: Here's a related fact that *is* true. Suppose $f$ is continuous, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$, and $\lim_{x\to\infty} f'(x)=C$ exists. Then $C=0$. To see this, apply the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$f(x)-f(0) = \int_0^x f'(s)\,ds.$$

The left side converges to $L-f(0)$, whereas the right grows arbitrarily large unless $C=0.$

Comment: How about the other way around? How would you prove it if it is?

Comment: The other way around is true. If f(x) approaches a finite value, say L, then the derivative approaches zero. Converse is not true, as indicated by others. I upvoted this problem, because it is an excellent topic for discussion for entry calc students!

Comment: @imranfat He just posted a counterexample; that function approaches 0 as $x$ gets large, but the derivative will always swing between -2 and 2.

Comment: Well I'll be darned. I need to write that one down. I learned something today!!!